# C# Convert string YYYYDDD to a normal date format

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datetime

quick question for you. I am trying to loop through a directory of files and rename them to a dateformat which is not Julian. All of the files are DailyFile.YYYYddd. I want to change them to DailyFile.mm-dd-yyyy. I can't seem to workout the julian date conversion. Can anyone offer some help? Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;

namespace TestingFileRename
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TestDirectory\", "MERSDLY.*");
        JulianCalendar juliCal = new JulianCalendar();
        foreach (string file in dirs)
        {   
            // Convert Julian date to MM-DD-yyyy format here and replace the filetail with it. 

            //file.move(file,filefront + new date string);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Suggest you read more about the [JulianCalendar][1] class.  I'd also strongly suggest to have the new format be DailyFile.yyyy-mm-dd for much better organization and sort order.

  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.juliancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TestDirectory\", "MERSDLY.*");
    foreach (string file in dirs)
    {
        var parts = file.Split("."); 
        var year = new DateTime(int.Parse(parts[1].Substring(0,4)), 1, 1);
        year = year.AddDays(int.Parse(parts[1].Substring(4)) - 1);
        parts[1] = year.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
        File.Move(file,string.Join(".", parts));
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks a ton! Helped me out big time!